# Splitting string into parallel arrays

Tags: arrays, string, concatenation

I am working on a project in C++ where I have a file with lines like this:
83YYYYYYYYYYThe Captain

I need to split into three parallel arrays like this:

83
YYYYYYYYYY
The Captain

I feel like I'm missing something obvious but I'm finding this very difficult.

Currently I'm using a loop with "isdigit" to get the first value.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The first array should be int, the second should be a two dimensional array with char values, and the third is string.

Answer (score 0):

What language are you doing this in? What is your criteria for splitting between the second and third fields? How do you decide the two dimensions for the second field? You don't really give enough information.

Comment: Sorry I'm like in a panic.  It's C++.  The second field is going to be a combination of Y's and N's, the third field will either be "The Captain" or "The New Guy"

Comment: I'm not sure why you find it difficult, but I would:
1) loop while isdigit (like you are)
2) loop while nextchar == 'N' || nextchar == 'Y'
3) Put what's left in your string.
I don't know how you determine the dimensions of your 2D array, unless you expect it to be square or something.